# SuperClass fields are not mapped in the subclass with PDO (php)

Tags: php, inheritance

I have the PersistentObject class as following

```
abstract class PersistentObject implements IPersistable
{
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

and the UserModel extending the PersistentObject

```
class UserModel extends PersistentObject
{
    public static $TABLE_NAME = "user";

    private $email;

    private $username;

    private $password;

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}
```

now when I fetch the usermodel with pdo

```
$entity = $stmt->fetchObject("UserModel");
```

I'm getting the result ( var_dump($entity) ):

```
object(UserModel)[11]
  private 'email' => string 'andrewwww@gmail.com' (length=24)
  private 'username' => string 'andrewww' (length=13)
  private 'password' => string '72bed4064dbe53d7fc5fd078214387c813c1f670' (length=40)
  private 'id' (PersistentObject) => null
  public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
```

and if I try

```
var_dump($entity->getId());
```

I receive null;

How is it possible to map the superclass fields into the subclass???
thnx!

Comment: When and where is the id set in the first place?

Comment: it creates a new id property on my usermodel subclass, but the id from superclass is null;

Comment: in every example of doing this, the model class has public fields. I am wondering that your setters are working for the other fields. As far as i know PDO is trying to set the public field of the given model class BEFORE the constructor is called. Is this really the original model you are using are there any contructors?

Comment: I am wondering about people who are downvoting questions without comments because they are not able to give an answer.

Comment: yes it is the original model. If I make an id field in the UserModel it works without problems, but I don't want to repeat the id field and its getter and setter for each model I have

Comment: Please try to change the id field of PersistentObject to `PUBLIC $id` instead of `PRIVATE $id`.

Comment: If I make the $id public it works, but that kills the encapsulation principle; Isn't it another way to do that?

Comment: I am still wondering why your setters work!!! Maybe PDO is using some kind of reflection to find your setters and this fails for your subclass but this is just an assumption. I think it is the common way to use public fields because of the given examples on php.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the difference between `private` and `protected`.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

So use `protected` in the parent class:

```
abstract class PersistentObject implements IPersistable
{
    protected $id;
    ...
```